# Spring OAuth2 Single Sign On redirects to wrong url

Tags: spring, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I'm developing a Single Sign On server using Spring OAuth2. My demo app includes 1 sso-server and 2 client apps (both clients either Spring apps with @EnableOAuth2Sso or Angular 5 apps). It works with the basic case:

1. An unauthenticated user opens app1/home -> redirect to oauth2/login
   -> login sucess -> redirect app1/home
2. The user open app2/home -> he dont need login and open app2/home immediately.

But the problem when following the flow:

1. An unauthenticated user opens app1/home -> redirect to oauth2/login
   (the user dont login immediately)
2. The user open app2/home -> redirect to oauth2/login (the user also dont
   login immediately)
3. The user login app1 -> **He is redirected unintentionally to App2 Home**
4. The user login app2 -> **He is redirected unintentionally to SSO Server Home**

And the error chain would continue when I get the app3, app4... . Summary, when I open many login browser tabs parallel and then actually login one of them I will be redirected to the last app that I opened.

Could anyone please give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of cookie: with the same browser the session cookie created and setted from spring at point 2 overwrites the cookie at point 1.

Continuing in the chain, at point 3, user1 login with cookie of user2, for this it will redirect to app2 home.